# Is Eruru Hakuoro's daughter?

Tags: utawarerumono

In the last episode of Utawarerumono we see that Iceman gives the baby he has with Mikoto this ring before they get attacked by the research facility.

[image: Ring given to baby]

The ring Eruru wears in her hair is the same one that had been given to Mikoto's baby.

[image: Ring on Eruru]

Does that mean that Eruru is Hakuro's daughter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so as Mikoto and Hakuro/Iceman only had one child while Eruru has her little sister Aruru. remember that the pact between Eruru and Utawarerumono was to save the life of her little sister Aruru who had just been killed during an earthquake<sup>1</sup>

However the Ring Eruru has is indeed the same same Hakuro gave to Mikoto as it is shown to have the same id credentials to access the research facility so it is more than likely Eruru and Aruru are decedents of Mikoto's and Hakuro's baby.

Also keep in mind that the Mecha used by Kuuya's Kingdom are the same as the ones the humans from the research facility used to survive outside and Kuuya's Kingdom seems to have been around for a while so i would suspect that a very long time has passed since Hakuro went ballistic in the research facility and turned all the humans in there into blobs. otherwise it's far too short of time for Mikoto's baby to reach Eruru's age while at the same span of time Kuuya's Kingdom are given the ability to use the Mecha and become one of the dominate forces on the continent

<sup>1: i think it was an earthquake which killed Aruru however i can't exactly remember. however i do remember from the visual novel it being revealed that Utawarerumono (or at least Hakuro) had appeared before Eruru and in exchnage for Aruru being revived Eruru was to become faithful to Hakuro which led him to question her love for him. she however ensures that she does love him herself and not because of the pact she made</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No, Eruru is Mikoto's reincarnation. The ring got to her by sheer fate as said in the game. The daughter he had with Mikoto was dissected by the scientists along with Mikoto. That is the reason the scientists were turned to slime by his powers in the first place. You can find all this information on the Wikipedia page on Utawarerumono.

Comment: Actually i thought Mikoto was still alive in the form of Kamyu and transforms back into Mikoto near the end

Comment: Nope, Kamyu is just the sort of reincarnation of Mutsumi, that bird girl from the test subjects (Number 63) made from Iceman's DNA and Mutsumi was special in the fact that she inherited more of his powers and thought of him as her father.